# Does using AdSense in slide-out div violate Google's TOS?

Tags: google-adsense

I want to encourage users to register on my website, so as a registered member perk, the ads would be removed, so I was thinking of implementing AdSense in a div that slides out from the bottom of the page and has a Close button (for non-registered users).  Would either of this be against Google's TOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did look at the [Adsense TOS](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms), and guess what ... here's what I found in clause 5, subclause (ii)

> (ii) edit, modify, filter, truncate or change the order of the information contained in any Ad, Link, Ad Unit, Search Result, or Referral Button, or remove, obscure or minimize any Ad, Link, Ad Unit, Search Result, or Referral Button in any way without authorization from Google;

Unless you can get this authorization from Google, I guess this is not possible.

I guess another method of doing what you want is to NOT generate the display of ads (instead of hiding them at the browser level) for your paying customers and display the ads for non-registered users.

Comment: Thanks.  That is interesting.  The place I got that idea was from YouTube as they show a little ad at the bottom of the video which has a close button.  Regarding the ads, I would use PHP to determine whether user is registered or not, so registered users wouldn't load the adsense code at all.  But my question was more regarding the slide-out mechanism and allowing users to close the ad.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's why they put in that authorization from Google clause!